# Верно ли, что И = ЬЫ?

Tags: орфография

Пусть:

1) слово "год" (ед. число) преобразуется в слово "годы" (мн. число),

2) слово "ель" (ед. число) преобразуется в слово "ели" (мн. число).

Верно ли, что последовательность из диакритического знака "ь" и буквы "ы" идентична букве "и" (например: трельы = трели, коньы = кони, копьы = копи, медведьы = медведи)?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете говорить и записывать: трель "ы" - трель с таким названием, но произношение "трельы" не получится - соответственно, такое письмо не имеет смысла.

После мягкого Л будет обязательно следовать "мягкий" гласный  верхнего подъема И, как  в слове "трели", или звук Й при записи "трельи".

Comment: 1. Спасибо.

2. Если будет время, сообщите какие правила регулируют преобразование имени существительного в единственном числе именительного падежа во множественное  число указанного падежа.